# WinRun4J service example doesn't run

Tags: java, service, winrun4j

Does anyone know how to get the [WinRun4J service example](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) (ServiceTest class that is distributed with the software) to run? I'm on a Windows 7 box, 64 bit, and have the Java 7 JDK and JRE installed.

I performed the following:

1. Copied `WinRun4J64c.exe` to `C:\test`, renamed it `service64.exe`
2. Copied `service.ini` to C:\test, renamed it `service64.ini`
3. Finally, I copied `WinRun4JTest.jar` to `C:\test`.

First off, you have to run a command prompt as Administrator, otherwise you can't register the service. So in a command prompt, opened as Administrator, I entered the command:

```
C:\Test>service64.exe --WinRun4J:RegisterService
```

So far so good. But when I go to the Windows services panel to start the service, I get the error:

> "Error 1053: service did not respond ... in a timely fashion"

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. You need to also copy WinRun4j.jar to the directory as well or somewhere where it can be found in the classpath.

Comment: While true, that was [already mentioned .. over two months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186895/104223). No need to repost the same answer twice. When you gain sufficient reputation, you can [leave comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) beneath any post.

Comment: He meant.. WinRun4J.jar not WinRun4JTest.jar.. so its a different and useful answer..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have understood that you may have forgotten to copy `WinRun4JTest.jar` to the `C:\test`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check that you have the appropriate java JRE installed for the 32 and/or 64 bit version of WinRun4J.

A quick way to find this out is to enable logging by adding the following to service.ini:

log=C:/log.txt
log.overwrite=true

And the log should note if your issue is JVM related.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set JAVA_HOME? I was having the same problem and that solved my issue.